# How do I adjust width and height in iframe via css or javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I tried via css but it did not change, knowing that I can not change it in html

```css
.bootbox-body iframe {width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

```html
<div class="bootbox-body"><iframe  style="width:100%;height:30px;" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/IOwom_Gp__Q" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

iFrame is special in the sense, that it’s getting width and height as “separate from styles” attributes. 
Ex.

```
<iframe src="https://youtube.com" width="200" height="200"></iframe>
```

It works pretty miserable with actual css styles, at least most of it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
iframe{
       display: block;
       width:100%; 
       height:100%;

}
```